# DB2 Date Cast Error for Parameter Position 1

Tags: datetime, casting, db2

Attempting to cast a string (formatted as YYYY-MM-DD) as ISO date. It's already in the right format but it is erroring out.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM TABLE1
WHERE CHAR(VARCHAR((SUBSTRING(PARAMETER_VALUE,8,4)||
        CASE SUBSTRING(PARAMETER_VALUE,4,3) 
            WHEN 'Jan' THEN '-01-'
            WHEN 'Feb' THEN '-02-'
            WHEN 'Mar' THEN '-03-'
            WHEN 'Apr' THEN '-04-'
            WHEN 'May' THEN '-05-'
            WHEN 'Jun' THEN '-06-'
            WHEN 'Jul' THEN '-07-'
            WHEN 'Aug' THEN '-08-'
            WHEN 'Sep' THEN '-09-'
            WHEN 'Oct' THEN '-10-'
            WHEN 'Nov' THEN '-11-'
            WHEN 'Dec' THEN '-12-' END||
            SUBSTRING(PARAMETER_VALUE,1,2))
        ),ISO) > CURRENT DATE;
```

I receive the following error: The statement was not processed because the data type, length or value of the argument for the parameter in position "1" of routine "SYSIBM.CHAR" is incorrect. Parameter name: "".. SQLCODE=-171, SQLSTATE=42815, DRIVER=4.19.56

I am using IBM Data Studio to run this.

Comment: What are the input strings and what do you want to do?

Comment: I am converting from a text format of DD Mmm YYYY (so 04 Apr 2020 for example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PARAMETER_VALUE looks like it's DDMonYYYY if you wanted to use `TO_DATE` similar to:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM TABLE1
WHERE TO_DATE(PARAMETER_VALUE, 'DDMonYYYY') > CURRENT DATE;
```

If that's not the correct format of that column then you can put together the correct string from here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0007107.html

Comment: I had to use TO_DATE on that obnoxious case when because the formatting was getting thrown, unable to format '20191124' or '24 Nov 2019' as a date. But it worked! Thank you.